# Over Silverman’s differential forms on curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I’m reading Silverman’s Arithmetic of Ellipctic curves. In II.4 he gives an definition of differential form as the set of $dx$ for $x$ in $\overline{K}(C)$. Taking the complex circle $x^2+y^2=1$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$. By 4.2(a), $xdy$ is a differential form. By definition there exists $t\in\overline{K}(C)$ such that $dt=xdy$.

If we integrate $\sqrt{1-y^2}dy$, it yields an $arcsin$, which suggests that such a function $t$ wouldn’t be algebraic...

What I’m I missing here? What is the function $t$ such that $dt=xdy$?

Comment: "By definition"? What definition is that?

Comment: The definition in II.4 in Silverman’s Arithmetics of Elliptic curves...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I think they mean the definition in the first sentence: Silverman defines differential forms to be things of the form $dt$ where $t\in\overline{K}(C)$. So if $xdy$ is a differential form then it should have this form

Comment: It’s the $\overline{k}-$vector space generated by these symbols... but since it’s linear we can add up and have d(ax+by+...)=adx+bdy+..., right?

Comment: Silverman says the $\overline{K}$-vector space generated by the symbols $dx, x \in \overline{K}(C)$. He meant the $\overline{K}(C)$-vector space ? ($dx$ is an exact meromorphic differential form for $x \in \overline{K}(C)$ and $x_2 dx$ is a (closed) meromorphic differential form for $x,x_2 \in \overline{K}(C)$) @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: I agree with reuns: I think it's a typo and it should be the $\overline{K}(C)$-vector space generated by $dx$ for $x \in \overline{K}(C)$. Indeed, without an action of $\overline{K}(C)$, how can one even define $x dy$? Or state the Leibniz rule: $d(xy) = x dy + y dx$?

Comment: Agree with reuns and André. The space of differential forms is a 1-dimensional space over $\overline{K}(C)$. Observe that differentiating both sides of $x^2+y^2=1$ yields $x\,dx+y\,dy=0$. In other words,
$$dy=-\frac xy\,dx.$$ All in line with $dx$ and $dy$ being linearly dependent over $K(C)$.